# MAUI Android UPD Client

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am trying to receive UDP packets on Android, but the error System.Net.Sockets is displayed.SocketException: 'Cannot assign requested address'

```
private void InitializeUdpClient()
{
    udpClient = new UdpClient();
    udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.##.###"), 8001));
    udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = timeOut;
}
```

the same code works on Windows

Tried a lot, checked ping, ping is

Comment: You shouldn't use a specific IP address, just do `Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8001));`